# Why can't stepper motors be powered off of 9V batteries?

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor

According to [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/powering-motors), "you can't run motors off of a 9V battery so don't waste your time/batteries!"

I've been searching around and it seems like most sources do use wall adapters, but without justifying why. What's the explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't quite accurate to say that you "CAN'T" operate stepper motors from 9V batteries. They actually mean that most stepper motors draw so much current that they won't run very long from a 9V battery before draining it completely. Quite possibly in a matter of minutes.  So it is an incredible waste of batteries to power something that needs that much power from a 9V battery. It has the LOWEST power density of ANY commonly available consumer battery. Even less than a AA cell.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* run stepper motors on 9V batteries. You just have to respect the batteries limitations:

[image]

[image]

Imgs from [this](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf) datasheet.

Which means, a limited amount of current (typically 300mA max), at a low-ish voltage 4V~9V, during maybe 1~2 hours.

So it's not impossible, it just doesn't make much sense, thats all.

Answer (score 3):

9V batteries have a terrible current rating and capacity since they're made of six smaller 1.5V cells. Since stepper motors need to have *two* coils energized at a time there is very little chance that you can use anything but the smallest of stepper motors for very long with one.